# Invalid format error when I try to encode to Base64

Tags: python, base64

I am trying to encode something to base64 but I am getting an invalid format error. How can this be solved?

```
creqBytes = bytes(f'{"threeDSServerTransID":threeDSServerTransID,"transStatus":"Y","acsTransID":acsTransID,"messageType":"CRes","messageVersion":"2.1.0"}', 'utf-8')
creq2 = base64.b64encode(creqBytes).decode("ascii")
print(creq2)
```

Comment: It looks like you're trying to create a JSON string?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I can't understand what steps you expect the code to take or how you expect it to work or what you think the result should be; and I can't even begin to guess what `threeDSServerTransID` or `acsTransID` is. Please read [ask] and https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ and [mre]. You should notice that the problem occurs **before** any attempt at encoding in base64; therefore this is **not a question about** base64 encoding. In fact, this code doesn't even create the `bytes` object; it fails at even creating *the original string*.

Comment: Consider that part of the code by itself, and consider a simpler example. Suppose I have code like `f'{"foo":bar}'`. Exactly what do you think this should mean? **Why**? In fact, what do you actually think the `f` means, and how do you think it works?

Answer (score 0):

The `ValueError: Invalid format specifier` error message you are getting is from your first line. This is because you have an `f` before the string indicates that this will be a string with [f-string](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/) formatting in it. However, you haven't put any f-string formatting in the string. Hence the error message.

I was able to get this to run by removing the `f`. Here is my test:

```py
import base64

creqBytes = bytes('{"threeDSServerTransID":threeDSServerTransID,"transStatus":"Y","acsTransID":acsTransID,"messageType":"CRes","messageVersion":"2.1.0"}', 'utf-8')
print(creqBytes)
# b'{"threeDSServerTransID":threeDSServerTransID,"transStatus":"Y","acsTransID":acsTransID,"messageType":"CRes","messageVersion":"2.1.0"}'

creq2 = base64.b64encode(creqBytes).decode("ascii")
print(creq2)
# eyJ0aHJlZURTU2VydmVyVHJhbnNJRCI6dGhyZWVEU1NlcnZlclRyYW5zSUQsInRyYW5zU3RhdHVzIjoiWSIsImFjc1RyYW5zSUQiOmFjc1RyYW5zSUQsIm1lc3NhZ2VUeXBlIjoiQ1JlcyIsIm1lc3NhZ2VWZXJzaW9uIjoiMi4xLjAifQ==
```

However, I suspect that isn't what you are trying to do. My guess would be that you have some variables in Python that you want to include in the string.
If that is the case then the f-string would look like:

```py
import base64

threeDSServerTransID = 2
acsTransID = 3

creqBytes = bytes(f'{{"threeDSServerTransID":{threeDSServerTransID},"transStatus":"Y","acsTransID":{acsTransID},"messageType":"CRes","messageVersion":"2.1.0"}}', 'utf-8')
print(creqBytes)
# b'{"threeDSServerTransID":2,"transStatus":"Y","acsTransID":3,"messageType":"CRes","messageVersion":"2.1.0"}'
creq2 = base64.b64encode(creqBytes).decode("ascii")
print(creq2)
# eyJ0aHJlZURTU2VydmVyVHJhbnNJRCI6MiwidHJhbnNTdGF0dXMiOiJZIiwiYWNzVHJhbnNJRCI6MywibWVzc2FnZVR5cGUiOiJDUmVzIiwibWVzc2FnZVZlcnNpb24iOiIyLjEuMCJ9
```

That formatting of the f-string looks like it would be error prone and difficult for other people to read.
I suspect that having the data as a Python dictionary and outputting it to a JSON format before then doing base64 encoding might be easier to understand and read. This would look like:

```py
import base64
import json

threeDSServerTransID = 2
acsTransID = 3

var1 = {
    "threeDSServerTransID": threeDSServerTransID,
    "transStatus": "Y",
    "acsTransID": acsTransID,
    "messageType": "CRes",
    "messageVersion": "2.1.0"
}
var2 = json.dumps(var1)
print(var2)
# '{"threeDSServerTransID": 2, "transStatus": "Y", "acsTransID": 3, "messageType": "CRes", "messageVersion": "2.1.0"}'

var3 = base64.b64encode(var2.encode())
print(var3)
# b'eyJ0aHJlZURTU2VydmVyVHJhbnNJRCI6IDIsICJ0cmFuc1N0YXR1cyI6ICJZIiwgImFjc1RyYW5zSUQiOiAzLCAibWVzc2FnZVR5cGUiOiAiQ1JlcyIsICJtZXNzYWdlVmVyc2lvbiI6ICIyLjEuMCJ9'
print(var3.decode('ascii'))
# eyJ0aHJlZURTU2VydmVyVHJhbnNJRCI6IDIsICJ0cmFuc1N0YXR1cyI6ICJZIiwgImFjc1RyYW5zSUQiOiAzLCAibWVzc2FnZVR5cGUiOiAiQ1JlcyIsICJtZXNzYWdlVmVyc2lvbiI6ICIyLjEuMCJ9
```